# Web Method Description Annotation in Java/Jax-ws?

Tags: java, web-services

In .net, you can have something like this:
    [WebMethod(Description="you explain what this web method do here ")]
    public double MyMethod(...)
    {

```
}
```

So is there a java equivalent annotation for "Description" so that the user will know what the webmethod does?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to provide the WebMethod with code comments